# How do you get the currently spoken word in Amazon Polly?

Tags: ios, swift, amazon-web-services, text-to-speech, amazon-polly

I'm using Amazon Polly for text-to-speech functionality of my app. I have succeeded in developing it except for one thing. I can't get the current spoken word so I can highlight it on the screen. I know in AVSpeechSynthetizerDelegate, we have this function: `AVSpeechSynthetizerDelegate.speechSynthesizer(_:willSpeakRangeOfSpeechString:utterance:` to do this. Is there any other similar function in Amazon Polly for this?

Thanks

Comment: What do you mean by "the currently spoken word"? I thought that Polly returns an MP3 stream or an MP3 file. Polly is not responsible for 'playing' the file. How are you playing the audio?

Comment: @JohnRotenstein I am playing it with AVPlayer just like the example. I now that it is streamed and we couldn't get it from there. However, from what I've read in the docs, there is a feature called Speech Mark that can be used for this but it is done with AWS CLI. https://docs.aws.amazon.com/polly/latest/dg/using-speechmarks.html